# League of legends crashes on Windows 8.1

Tags: league-of-legends, windows-8

My PC is currently running on the Windows 8.1. When the league of legends launcher is ready to play it crashes the game. Can you give me an answer to how I can make league of legends work on Windows 8.1 ?

Comment: With so little information it's **most unlikely**

Comment: Works fine on my Windows 8.1.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the EventLog you can share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try running the game with administrator privileges,
like this:
[image: enter screenshot]

Comment: Does something miss in the screenshot ?

Comment: This used to happen to me and that is what I had to do. It worked after that and should work for him.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't work in admin mode, go into the patcher, click the gear and go repair.
Then try and play, if this doesn't work try reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Playing on Windows 8.1

My  issue i was playing  LOL however  the  very  next  day, my client was crashing i had  the  bug splat showing up every  time  i opened the client, so  i uninstalled  LOL  thinking  something  got  corrupted, then when i tried to  re-install, the  installer crashed .

SOLUTION

installed updated video card  drives from windows update ..not automatically done they were sitting there... after restarted  the  comp and tried the  installer again 
 no compatibility mode  or  anything  and   it  worked  i  wish  i had updated the  graphic  card  before   uninstalling  lol i  likely  would have  saved the installation  time  ...hope  it  works 4 u